Nextjs Typescript Error deconstructing params in api route
I Have a next project when I build it, it works fine localy but on vercel keeps throwing this error no matter what I try
Type error: Route "[action]/route.ts" has an invalid "POST" export:
  Type "NextResponse<unknown>" is not a valid type for the function's second argument.
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

This is my current code and I've tried many variation of it but it wont let me build
declare module "next/server" {
  interface NextResponse {
    params: { action: string }; // Add your custom property here
  }
}
export const POST = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  const { params } = await res;

  if (!params || !params.action)
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false, message: "Incorrect usage" });

  const action = params.action;

  
  ...


Also tried expanding
interface MyResponse extends NextResponse {
  params: { action: string }; // Add your custom property here
}
export const POST = async (req: NextRequest, res: MyResponse) => {

Any help would be much appreciated

You would get the same error locally by building it with next build.
Route Handlers have a different signature with App Router, see the official docs.
If you rely on your response, try awaiting it from the request as follows:
export const POST = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const data = await req.json();
  const { params } = await data as MyResponse;

  if (!params || !params.action)
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false, message: "Incorrect usage" });

  const action = params.action;
  ...
};

